# Is it safe to rollback Wubi without fresh Wubi install?

Tags: installation, 12.10, wubi, xubuntu

I've installed Ubuntu 12.10, then I made a backup from `root.disk` file. I decided to change from Ubuntu to Xubuntu. So I downloaded Xubuntu 12.10 ISO image and reinstalled Wubi.

In case I'm want to rollback to Ubuntu, is it safe to copy `root.disk` to C:\ubuntu\disks without reinstalling Wubi first to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's safe as long as they're the same release (which they are in this case) and you installed to the same partition (`C:`).

When you boot your computer it will still offer a choice between *Windows* and *Xubuntu* but it will boot whatever is on the `root.disk`. If you wanted to change the boot entry back to *Ubuntu* you'd have to use `bcdedit` or `easyBCD` (for Windows 8/7/Vista) or edit the boot.ini (Windows XP).

Wubi boots via `grub4dos` (`wubildr.mbr`) and a version of `grub2` in `wubildr`. What they do is locate the first `/ubuntu/disks/root.disk` it finds on any partition, and then load the Grub menu (`grub.cfg`) from within that `root.disk`. So it doesn't matter what is on that `root.disk` (or even what partition, provided in the `grub.cfg` it has the correct partition `UUID`). So if you installed on `C:` it has to be on `C:` or you have to manually edit the Grub menu entry before booting.

The only issue is that the modules built into `wubildr` must be compatible with the `grub.cfg` so changing releases can lead to incompatibilities. In these cases you can sometimes manually boot from a grub prompt, but it's best to stick to the same one to avoid issues.

Comment: It works, because I used it from same releases